# Not getting error code when fails copying remote MySQL DB using PHP -> SSH -> MYSQLDUMP

Tags: php, ssh, mysql

I created a script to copy a remote database using mysqldump inside a SSH connection. Then i ported to my PHP script so i can better manage several servers.

My problem is when the copy fails... I get no error code from the command.

This is the command:

ssh -p22 -i mykey.key -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null backup@hostname "mysqldump -hlocalhost -udbuser --databases db" > myfile.sql

It works =)

PHP code with simplified systax:

```
$comando = 'ssh -i mykey.key backup@hostname "mysqldump --databases db" > myfile.sql';
$ret_text = exec($comando, $output, $ret);
// Doesnt matter if command fails or sucess, result is?
//$ret = empty
//$output = empty
//$ret_text = empty
```

I need to know when the copy failed, does anyone know how to get a remote error code?

Thanks

Comment: What about directing stderr to stdout via `2>&1`?

Comment: I'll try and respond

Comment: since the failure's on the remote end and the exit code wouldn't be transmitted back, you'd just get no output at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neubert Solution Works! Thanks...

I ended with:

```
$comando = 'ssh -i mykey.key backup@hostname "mysqldump --databases db 2>&1\" 2>&1 > myfile.sql';
```